# Android 3.2 missing dialer?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using the Android 3.2 emulator. I can't find the dialer. Hitting F3 does not bring up the telephone app. Many other things don't work. For example, in the Settings app, I can't go into individual settings page (like Language and input). Is this thing half cooked?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find the dialer.

Android 3.2 is for tablets. There is no dialer.

> For example, in the Settings app, I can't go into individual settings page (like Language and input).

Launch Settings and click on "Language & input" on the left.

If by this you meant:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS));
```

that too works on my copy of the Android 3.2 emulator.

Comment: > Android 3.2 is for tablets. There is no dialer.
Thanks. That helps. 

> Launch Settings and click on "Language & input" 
I am doing that. But nothing happens. Anyway, that is a moot point now.
I have to drop down to SDK 2.3.3 to get the phone dialer.

Comment: @Raj: "I am doing that. But nothing happens" -- FWIW, it works in my 3.2 emulator.